# Node.js Mongoose: Convert DOB to Date showing wrong time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

If I submit the day as 5, the moth as 12 and the year as 1975 with the below function the output is `"1975-12-04T16:00:00.000Z"` why is the day changed from the 5th to the 4th? and why is the hour 16? and the 2 extra milliseconds? What's going on?

```
      if (req.body.year && req.body.month && req.body.day) {
        dob = new Date(`${req.body.year}-${req.body.month}-${req.body.day}`);
        dob.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        // dob then gets saved to mongo as a `Date`
      }
```

The scema is defined as

```
dob: { type: Date },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because mongo converts it to UTC. See the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/#overview).

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local
>   time representations into this form. Applications that must operate or
>   report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone
>   alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in
>   their application logic.

Comment: It feels wrong to store the date of birth for everyone at 16 hours, should I save it as a string instead? Or add 8 hours on?

Comment: You could do something like this: `new Date('1975-12-05T00:00:00.000Z')`. It means the timestamp is already in UTC so mongo wouldn't convert it. But, I won't suggest it. Because, it is always a good idea to store timestamp in UTC so that you can convert to another timezone easily.